# Delete end of a string in a dataset (python)

Tags: python, string, dataset

I have a dataset with some dates in a column.
The thing is that some of the dates are composed of 2 dates, like 2010-2011.
I want to delete the second date on all of my dataset, basically having `date = date[:4]`
I tried that but that didn't work (my dataset has 61 rows) :

```
for i in [0,60]:  
    df['Date'][i] = df['Date'][i][:4]
```

The goal is to select rows of the dataset based on this date by comparing them (so I need them as integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it all in one line as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

#Example data
data = pd.DataFrame()
data['date'] = ['2010', '2010-2011', '2012', '2009-2010']

#Split on '-' and make integer
data['date'] = data['date'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')[0]).astype('int')

#Print update dataframe
data
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.slice(0, 4)
df['Date'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Date'])
```

Note that these operations are applied to the entire column instead of operating over the rows, which is generally considered more idiomatic when using `pandas`, they have [lots of useful library methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str) for performing similar transformations easily.

Also minor note about the code you provided: Keep in mind that `[0,60]` means "`0` and `60`", whereas I think you intended to write something like `range(61)`, producing all numbers from `0` up to and including `60`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> date = "2011-2013"             #our Input
>>> date.split("-")                #split out input using -
['2011', '2013']                   #output
>>> date.split("-")[0]             #get the first date 'string'
'2011'                             #output
>>> int(date.split("-")[0])        #get the first date 'integer'
2011                               #output
>>>
```

Comment: It is beneficial for the long-term value of your post if you explained your solution not just presented code

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb try using python comprehension rather than pandas instance methods.
an example of a pandas instance method is something like this
`df['Date'].str.slice(0, 4)`. In this case `.str` is the instance method of the dataframe `df['Date']`. Instead use list comprehensions as such:

`df['Date'] = [i[:4] for i in df['Date']]`

if you want to be more specific and do your split based on the dash between 2010-2011 do the following:

`df['Date'] = [i.split("-")[0] for i in df['Date']]`

to change the datatype do:

`df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(int)`
however this isn't a date time format. It's just an integer.